# WPF TargetUpdated event not firing on ContentControl

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I'm using an attached property to subscrive to the TargetUpdated event from a TextBlock, so I can be notified every time the text changes.

Using the following XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type targetUpdatedApp:Item}">
        <targetUpdatedApp:LabelControl Text="{Binding Text, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Style="{StaticResource LabelTemplateStyle}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <!--<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" targetUpdatedApp:DesiredWidth.DesiredMinWidth="120"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>-->
    </ListBox>

    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is my AttachedProperty code:

```
public class DesiredWidth
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DesiredMinWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "DesiredMinWidth", typeof (double),
            typeof (TextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(OnDesiredMinWidthChanged));

    public static double GetDesiredMinWidth(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double) obj.GetValue(DesiredMinWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDesiredMinWidth(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DesiredMinWidthProperty, value);
    }

    static void OnDesiredMinWidthChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var textBlock = obj as TextBlock;
        if (textBlock == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (args.NewValue != null)
        {
            textBlock.TargetUpdated += OnTextBoxTargetUpdated;     
        }
    }

    static void OnTextBoxTargetUpdated(object sender, System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Property == TextBlock.TextProperty)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The Items collection binded to the `ListBox` is an `ObservableCollection` and the items on it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
If I uncomment the code of the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` and use it instead of the style it works ok, but I use LabelControl (which basically has a Text `DependencyProperty`) described on the style the `TargetUpdated` event subscribed on the `AttachedProperty` never gets fired.

Could someone give me some help on this issue?
Thanks in advance.

PS: Added from comment :

```
<Style x:Key="LabelTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type argetUpdatedApp:LabelControl}">      
     <Setter Property="Template"> 
         <Setter.Value> 
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type targetUpdatedApp:LabelControl}"> 
                 <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" TargetUpdatedApp:DesiredWidth.DesiredMinWidth="120"/> 
             </ControlTemplate> 
         </Setter.Value> 
     </Setter> 
</Style>
```

Comment: Added missing Style:

<Style x:Key="LabelTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type targetUpdatedApp:LabelControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type targetUpdatedApp:LabelControl}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" targetUpdatedApp:DesiredWidth.DesiredMinWidth="120"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

Comment: it would be better if you but that comment in the question. better to read

Answer (score 0):

`NotifyOnTargetUpdated` will only apply to the binding that it's set on, not bindings on elements contained within. You have this set on the `LabelControl`, but the event handler is attached to the `TextBlock` inside its ControlTemplate, which isn't notifying. Use:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type targetUpdatedApp:LabelControl}">
    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" targetUpdatedApp:DesiredWidth.DesiredMinWidth="120"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Another way you could do this, which wouldn't require you to edit bindings, is to use another attached property instead of the element's own `Text` property:

```
<TextBlock DesiredWidth.Text="{Binding Text}" DesiredWidth.MinWidth="120" />
```

And in `DesiredWidth` you could then add a `OnTextChanged` callback that passes the value on to the TextBlock's `Text` and does any other handling needed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

I tried the first approach and the code is unable to compile, since I'm using a TemplateBinding NotifyOnTargetUpdated is not supported.

On the second approach it throws an exception on startup, the attached property type I would need to create would be of BindingExpression instead of string.

Comment: @HelderCosta The attached property should work. Make sure you are declaring it correctly. I noticed in your question you are using `typeof(TextBlock)` in your `RegistereAttached`. This should be the type where it's declared instead (`typeof(DesiredWidth)`).